# Request.UrlReferrer not working on controller page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use `Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery` method on my controller as `return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);`, but It's always getting current page URL, I guess my login page inside a controller which name is AccountController, so this method not getting out of that controller. Because when I try to use `@Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery` on the `_Layout`, It's working well. Do you know the solution?

Comment: Are you trying to call it inside the method with `HttpPostAttribute`?

Comment: Please include your source code. Also please detail what value it is returning, and what value you **expect** it to return.

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov Yeap, I'm trying to call it in [HttpPost]

Comment: Don't rely on the referrer. It is user-supplied and thus untrustable; it also won't be provided in various scenarios.

Comment: As @CodeCaster rightly said, don't rely on `UrlReferrer`. If you need to redirect a user back to the previous URL, then you should pass that previous URL as part of your request. Make sure also to employ `Url.IsLocaLUrl` to check the return URL before redirecting. This ensures that it can only be a URL on your website, preventing users from misdirecting requests by altering to go to some other domain.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have `Action1` from what you are going to `Action2`, performing some work on it, posting it to `Action2` with `HttpPostAttribute` and want to go back to `Action1`. And everything work synchronously, without AJAX.

You should not use `Request.UrlReferrer` as it does not provide desired values. It contains the address to page, from what you come to `Action2` with `HttpPost`, it is obviously `Action2` with `[HttpGet]` or without attributes (similar to `[HttpGet]`).

First way if user should be permanently redirect to the required page, is to use `RedirectToAction` method of controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action1", "YourControllerName");
```

Another way is to store url to redirect on the hidden input on client side. It is requiring modifying controller's code:

```
public ActionResult Action2(string backUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(backUrl)) 
    { 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("backUrl"); 
    }
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = backUrl;
    //your work
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action2(YourModel model, string backUrl)
{
    //your work
    return Redirect(backUrl);
}
```

And on the client side:

Action1 view:

```
...
@Html.ActionLink("text", "Action2", new { backUrl = Url.Action("Action1") })
...
```

Action2 view (inside a form):

```
...
<input name='backUrl' type='hidden' value='@ViewBag.ReturnUrl' />
...
```

And everything should work.

Comment: While this is technically correct, you should wrap the return in a conditional that checks `Url.IsLocalUrl(backUrl)`. This prevents a security hole where a malicious third party could post something like a login form to your site and via the return URL, redirect the user back to their malicious site. allowing them to perform phishing attacks on your users.